# R Looping thru list of codes from a column

Tags: r, for-loop, split, data.table

I have a large data set, which I need to split into multiple datasets based on area column and then execute some set of codes for each area and get output data for each area. I was trying to do this using a for loop but it does not seem to work. How can this be achieved. below is the code I was trying -

```
for (a in c('10','11','14','20','30','40','50','61','64'))
{
  paste0("data3_add_area",a) <- data3_add[AREACODE == a,]
  paste0("in_add_area",a) <- in_add[AREA_CODE == a,]

  source1 <- paste0("data3_add_area",a)$name
  source2 <- paste0("in_add_area",a)$name
  .....
  paste0("match_",a) <- output

}
```

Can we do something like this in R. Sorry I am still learning R and not sure about the feasibility. What is the best way to achieve this?

**EDIT - SAMPLE DATA**

```
Address1 <- c("786, GALI NO 5, XYZ","rambo, 45, strret 4, atlast, pqr","23/4, 23RD FLOOR, STREET 2, ABC-E, PQR","45-B, GALI NO5, XYZ","HECTIC, 99 STREET, PQR")
AREACODE <- c('10','11','14','20','30')
Year1 <- c(2001:2005)

Address2 <- c("abc, pqr, xyz","786, GALI NO 4 XYZ","45B, GALI NO 5, XYZ","del, 546, strret2, towards east, pqr","23/4, STREET 2, PQR","abc, pqr, xyz","786, GALI NO 4 XYZ","45B, GALI NO 5, XYZ","del, 546, strret2, towards east, pqr","23/4, STREET 2, PQR")
Year2 <- c(2001:2010)
AREA_CODE <- c('10','11','14','20','30','40','50','61','64')

data3_add <- data.table(Address1,Year1,AREACODE)
in_add <- data.table(Address2,Year2,AREA_CODE)
in_add [,unique_id := sprintf("%06d", 1:nrow(in_add))]
```

**CODE that I want to replicate for each area ( ref from this link - https://www.r-bloggers.com/fuzzy-string-matching-a-survival-skill-to-tackle-unstructured-information/)**

using method2 I want to replicate the code for each area -

```
#install.packages('stringdist')
library(stringdist)

distance.methods<-c('osa','lv','dl','hamming','lcs','qgram','cosine','jaccard','jw')
dist.methods<-list()
for(m in 1:length(distance.methods))
{
  dist.name.enh<-matrix(NA, ncol = length(source2.devices$name),nrow = length(source1.devices$name))
  for(i in 1:length(source2.devices$name)) {
    for(j in 1:length(source1.devices$name)) { 
      dist.name.enh[j,i]<-stringdist(tolower(source2.devices[i,]$name),tolower(source1.devices[j,]$name),method = distance.methods[m])      
        #adist.enhance(source2.devices[i,]$name,source1.devices[j,]$name)
    }  
  }
  dist.methods[[distance.methods[m]]]<-dist.name.enh
}

match.s1.s2.enh<-NULL
for(m in 1:length(dist.methods))
{

  dist.matrix<-as.matrix(dist.methods[[distance.methods[m]]])
  min.name.enh<-apply(dist.matrix, 1, base::min)
  for(i in 1:nrow(dist.matrix))
  {
    s2.i<-match(min.name.enh[i],dist.matrix[i,])
    s1.i<-i
    match.s1.s2.enh<-rbind(data.frame(s2.i=s2.i,s1.i=s1.i,s2name=source2.devices[s2.i,]$name, s1name=source1.devices[s1.i,]$name, adist=min.name.enh[i],method=distance.methods[m]),match.s1.s2.enh)
  }
}
# Let's have a look at the results
library(reshape2)
matched.names.matrix<-dcast(match.s1.s2.enh,s2.i+s1.i+s2name+s1name~method, value.var = "adist")
View(matched.names.matrix)
```

Comment: could you provide some reproducible data? `dput(head(data2_add, 20))` for example and maybe `in_add`.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `split`, which can split a data.frame into a list of data.frames based on the values of some vector. `myList <- split(data3_add, data3_add$AREACODE)`. gregor's answer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) could also be helpful for working with lists of data.frames.

Comment: @Frank, Thank you for pointing it out. I have updated the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete script, I changed the input sets a little to demonstrate the situation where the distance matrix has more than one row and one column:

```
library("stringdist")
library("data.table")

Address1 <- c("786, GALI NO 5, XYZ","rambo, 45, strret 4, atlast, pqr","23/4, 23RD FLOOR, STREET 2, ABC-E, PQR","45-B, GALI NO5, XYZ","HECTIC, 99 STREET, PQR")
AREACODE <- c('10','10','14','20','30')
Year1 <- c(2001:2005)

Address2 <- c("abc, pqr, xyz","786, GALI NO 4 XYZ","45B, GALI NO 5, XYZ","del, 546, strret2, towards east, pqr","23/4, STREET 2, PQR","abc, pqr, xyz","786, GALI NO 4 XYZ","45B, GALI NO 5, XYZ","del, 546, strret2, towards east, pqr","23/4, STREET 2, PQR")
Year2 <- c(2001:2010)
AREA_CODE <- c('10','10','10','20','30','40','50','61','64', '99')

data1 <- data.table(Address1, Year1, AREACODE)
data2 <- data.table(Address2, Year2, AREA_CODE)
data2[, unique_id := sprintf("%06d", 1:nrow(data2))]

methods <- c('osa','lv','dl','hamming','lcs','qgram','cosine','jaccard','jw')

# split data.table into list of data.tables by area code
sdata1 <- split(data1, data1$AREACODE)
sdata2 <- split(data2, data2$AREA_CODE)

# find the unique codes
codes <- union(names(sdata1), names(sdata2))


dist_calc <- function(x, y, methods) {
  distance_methods <- list()

  # calculate distance for each method
  for(m in seq_along(methods)) {
    output <- matrix(NA, ncol = length(x), nrow = length(y))
    for(i in seq_along(x)) {
      for(j in seq_along(y)) { 
        # calculate the matrix of distances for each pairing
        output[j, i] <- stringdist(tolower(x[i]), tolower(y[j]), method = methods[m])
      }  
    }
    # store the output matrix in a named list element
    distance_methods[[methods[m]]] <- output
  }
  # return a list of lists, with each leaf element being a matrix
  return(distance_methods)
}


# iterate over codes, use names to retain codes and do not simplify -- return a list
distances <- sapply(codes, function(code) {
  x <- sdata1[[code]]$Address1
  y <- sdata2[[code]]$Address2

  # do not compute if the code is not present in either one, the other or both
  if (is.null(x) | is.null(y))
    return(NULL)

  # calculate all the distances
  dist_mats <- dist_calc(x, y, methods)

  # calculate the minimum value and indicie for each method
  method_mins <- sapply(methods, function(meth) {

    min_col <- apply(dist_mats[[meth]], 1, which.min)
    min_val <- apply(dist_mats[[meth]], 1, min)

    # list the minimum match value, the string, the matching string
    data.table(name = y, match_name = x[min_col], adist = min_val)
  }, USE.NAMES = TRUE, simplify = FALSE)

  # combine into a single data.table
  rbindlist(method_mins, idcol = "method")

}, USE.NAMES = TRUE, simplify = FALSE)

all_distances <- rbindlist(Filter(function(x) !is.null(x), distances), idcol = "AREACODE")

#    AREACODE  method                                 name                       match_name       adist
# 1:       10     osa                        abc, pqr, xyz              786, GALI NO 5, XYZ 12.00000000
# 2:       10     osa                   786, GALI NO 4 XYZ              786, GALI NO 5, XYZ  2.00000000
# 3:       10     osa                  45B, GALI NO 5, XYZ              786, GALI NO 5, XYZ  3.00000000
# 4:       10      lv                        abc, pqr, xyz              786, GALI NO 5, XYZ 12.00000000
# 5:       10      lv                   786, GALI NO 4 XYZ              786, GALI NO 5, XYZ  2.00000000
# 6:       10      lv                  45B, GALI NO 5, XYZ              786, GALI NO 5, XYZ  3.00000000
# 7:       10      dl                        abc, pqr, xyz              786, GALI NO 5, XYZ 12.00000000
# 8:       10      dl                   786, GALI NO 4 XYZ              786, GALI NO 5, XYZ  2.00000000
# 9:       10      dl                  45B, GALI NO 5, XYZ              786, GALI NO 5, XYZ  3.00000000
#10:       10 hamming                        abc, pqr, xyz              786, GALI NO 5, XYZ         Inf
#11:       10 hamming                   786, GALI NO 4 XYZ              786, GALI NO 5, XYZ         Inf
#12:       10 hamming                  45B, GALI NO 5, XYZ              786, GALI NO 5, XYZ  3.00000000
#13:       10     lcs                        abc, pqr, xyz              786, GALI NO 5, XYZ 18.00000000
#14:       10     lcs                   786, GALI NO 4 XYZ              786, GALI NO 5, XYZ  3.00000000
#15:       10     lcs                  45B, GALI NO 5, XYZ              786, GALI NO 5, XYZ  6.00000000
#16:       10   qgram                        abc, pqr, xyz              786, GALI NO 5, XYZ 16.00000000
#17:       10   qgram                   786, GALI NO 4 XYZ              786, GALI NO 5, XYZ  3.00000000
#18:       10   qgram                  45B, GALI NO 5, XYZ              786, GALI NO 5, XYZ  6.00000000
#19:       10  cosine                        abc, pqr, xyz rambo, 45, strret 4, atlast, pqr  0.31400566
#20:       10  cosine                   786, GALI NO 4 XYZ              786, GALI NO 5, XYZ  0.04653741
#21:       10  cosine                  45B, GALI NO 5, XYZ              786, GALI NO 5, XYZ  0.08784068
#22:       10 jaccard                        abc, pqr, xyz rambo, 45, strret 4, atlast, pqr  0.63157895
#23:       10 jaccard                   786, GALI NO 4 XYZ              786, GALI NO 5, XYZ  0.12500000
#24:       10 jaccard                  45B, GALI NO 5, XYZ              786, GALI NO 5, XYZ  0.29411765
#25:       10      jw                        abc, pqr, xyz              786, GALI NO 5, XYZ  0.42535425
#26:       10      jw                   786, GALI NO 4 XYZ              786, GALI NO 5, XYZ  0.05360624
#27:       10      jw                  45B, GALI NO 5, XYZ              786, GALI NO 5, XYZ  0.10526316
#28:       20     osa del, 546, strret2, towards east, pqr              45-B, GALI NO5, XYZ 29.00000000
#29:       20      lv del, 546, strret2, towards east, pqr              45-B, GALI NO5, XYZ 29.00000000
#30:       20      dl del, 546, strret2, towards east, pqr              45-B, GALI NO5, XYZ 29.00000000
#31:       20 hamming del, 546, strret2, towards east, pqr              45-B, GALI NO5, XYZ         Inf
#32:       20     lcs del, 546, strret2, towards east, pqr              45-B, GALI NO5, XYZ 41.00000000
#33:       20   qgram del, 546, strret2, towards east, pqr              45-B, GALI NO5, XYZ 35.00000000
#34:       20  cosine del, 546, strret2, towards east, pqr              45-B, GALI NO5, XYZ  0.46394373
#35:       20 jaccard del, 546, strret2, towards east, pqr              45-B, GALI NO5, XYZ  0.72000000
#36:       20      jw del, 546, strret2, towards east, pqr              45-B, GALI NO5, XYZ  0.54863548
#37:       30     osa                  23/4, STREET 2, PQR           HECTIC, 99 STREET, PQR 11.00000000
#38:       30      lv                  23/4, STREET 2, PQR           HECTIC, 99 STREET, PQR 11.00000000
#39:       30      dl                  23/4, STREET 2, PQR           HECTIC, 99 STREET, PQR 11.00000000
#40:       30 hamming                  23/4, STREET 2, PQR           HECTIC, 99 STREET, PQR         Inf
#41:       30     lcs                  23/4, STREET 2, PQR           HECTIC, 99 STREET, PQR 15.00000000
#42:       30   qgram                  23/4, STREET 2, PQR           HECTIC, 99 STREET, PQR 13.00000000
#43:       30  cosine                  23/4, STREET 2, PQR           HECTIC, 99 STREET, PQR  0.21927994
#44:       30 jaccard                  23/4, STREET 2, PQR           HECTIC, 99 STREET, PQR  0.50000000
#45:       30      jw                  23/4, STREET 2, PQR           HECTIC, 99 STREET, PQR  0.31607428
#    AREACODE  method                                 name                       match_name       adist
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. This is quite interesting to know, but at the same not that simple to replicate as I had thought. Is it necessary to have the areas as list? It would help if you could let me know why we need to use two [[]]? I have added the code that I wanted to replicate for each area. Could you please suggest where all I would need to add [[]] to get output for each area. Sorry I have been trying to replicate but getting some errors like - $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: You can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-and-notations-for-accessing-the-elements-of-a-lis) question to see when we use `[` and when we use `[[`

Comment: Thank you for replicating the code. I tried running you code but getting error at the last line of your code, "Error in rbindlist(distances, idcol = "AREACODE") : attempt to set index 5/5 in SET_STRING_ELT", I did a search on the net for this error and saw posts asking to update data.table and I updated the same, still this error. Would you know what could be causing this error?

Comment: I see the same error with data.table 1.10.4, r 3.2.5, Win 10. `rbindlist(Filter(function(x) !is.null(x), distances), idcol="AREACODE")` works fine I think, though @user1412

Comment: Thanks @Frank, it looks like I was using an outdated package version in which `NULL`s were silently dropped, thanks for the catch.

Comment: @mlegge, the code ran based on the update suggestion from Frank. It is great to have a consolidated output for all areas, I will need some time to digest the edit code and do some dry run. However based on the output, I realized that the key was to have outputs for each area. As address is in short form (excluding area details) and can be duplicated across areas, hence we would have better accuracy if we match at area level. So was hopping to have the outputs at area level. If we filter out from final output it might not be right as match might have happened with a different area from 2nd file